# How to sort wordpress posts already selected by WP_QUERY

Tags: wp-query, order, sort

English is not my first language, sorry :)

I need differend per paginate page sorting.

For exemple, I created the loop:

```
 $qargs = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 15,
                    'no_found_rows'  => true,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'suppress_filters' => false,
                    'orderby' => 'post_views', // here I order my posts by views
                    'fields' => '',
                    'date_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'after'     => '-7 days',
                            'column' => 'post_date',
                        ),
                    ),
posts_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
```

And now I can display 15 selected posts sorted by views like this:

```
if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ):
                    $posts_query->the_post();
.......
```

But I need to select 15 most viewed posts and **after that** to sort them by date.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This would need to be done using two queries.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way how to reorder already selected posts.

For exapmle, we have selected posts:

```
$qargs = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 15,
                'no_found_rows'  => true,
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'suppress_filters' => false,
                'orderby' => 'post_views', // here I order my posts by views
                'fields' => '',
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'after'     => '-7 days',
                        'column' => 'post_date',
                    ),
                ),
$posts_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
```

Now we can reorder these posts by date:

```
function order_by_date( $a, $b ) {
        return strcasecmp( $b->post_date, $a->post_date );
    }
usort( $posts_query->posts, 'order_by_date' );
```

And next, we can echo our posts:

```
if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ): ?>
            while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ):
                $posts_query->the_post();
.......
```